How to properly group radio buttons in React
I am currently learning React. I having difficulty understanding the code below regarding controlling radio buttons. I don't understand how the code manage to allow only one radio button to be selected at a time. As far as my understanding, this feature is possible if all the radio buttons has the same 'name' attributes so that they can be grouped as one.
import * as React from "react";

export const RadioGroup = ({ onChange, selected, children }) => { 
 const RadioOptions = React.Children.map(children, (child) => { 
    // console.log(child)
   return React.cloneElement(child, { 
     onChange, 
     checked: child.props.value === selected, 
   }); 
 }); 
//  console.log(RadioOptions)
 return <div className="RadioGroup">{RadioOptions}</div>; 
}; 
 
export const RadioOption = ({ value, checked, onChange, children }) => { 
 return ( 
   <div className="RadioOption"> 
     <input 
       id={value} 
       type="radio" 
       name={value} 
       value={value} 
       checked={checked} 
       onChange={(e) => { 
         onChange(e.target.value); 
       }} 
     /> 
     <label htmlFor={value}>{children}</label> 
   </div> 


Given child.props.value === selected, if the values are all different, only one can be equal to selected

@qrsngky the initial state value of selected is const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");

how does React group these buttons since there is no identical 'name' attributes in each components?

The checked property is specified like checked: child.props.value === selected. That means checked: true for at most one of them, and checked: false for the rest. The "name" does not even need to be considered

@qrsngky sorry but I still don't get it how the radio buttons are grouped.

Even with plain JS, it's not that hard to make it so that only one is selected, even without considering the names: `


`
What you were thinking was a default behavior of the browser (available even if you didn't add any JS), which automatically un-selects others with the same name.
But you can add JS to control the checked property of all the radio buttons, and in this case the functions were added by React.

Now I get it even if I'm still stuck or used to using 'name` attribute. Thanks @qrsngky
